# Using regex.replace() to add to ", and "to the third to last comma in a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a two scenarios which occur in my code:

1. A string that consist of just names and the last item does not have a designation (", CPA, CFA"). For instance, **"John, Jan, Joe"** and I use the code below to replace the last comma with and so I get **"John, Jan and Joe"**
2. A string that consist of names and a CPA/CFA designation (", CPA, CFA") at the end such as **"John, Jan, Joe, CPA, CFA"**. In this scenario I need to replace the third to the end commma with and to get **"John, Jan, and Joe, CPA, CFA"**. I just need to handle the case of that third to the end comma. **I will note these are just sample strings and really it could include more names** (i.e., it could "jake, jan, joe, john, jessie") but ultimately I am just checking if that last name has the designations(extra commas) and if so it should account for it by only adding the and to replace the third to last comma.

My goal is to properly add the and to the last item in the comma separated list to follow standard English practices. The designation commas for the last item throw off my Regex expression I was using to add that last and in replacement of the comma.

My code:

```
if(str1.EndsWith(", CPA, CFA"))
{
       //need to figure out
}
else
{
        Regex.Replace(str1, ", ([^,]+)$", " and $1");
}
```

Comment: How can you frame the "end" condition?

Comment: I suppose you can use the exact same regex for both. However in the CPA-case you just append that fix string at the end.

Comment: How would i use the same regex expression if I need to shift down to the third to last comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a pattern with 2 capture groups capturing the first comma and match the second comma

The the replacement use the 2 groups `$1 and $2`

```
([^\s,]+),\s*([^\s,]+(?:, CPA, CFA)?)$
```

The pattern matches:

- `([^\s,]+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars and a comma
- `,\s*` Match a comma and optional whitespace chars
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^\s,]+` Match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char or comma
  - `(?:, CPA, CFA)?` Optionally match `, CPA, CFA`
- `)` Close group 2
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KvibCz/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/eyy9dd)

Example

```
string pattern = @"([^\s,]+),\s*([^\s,]+(?:, CPA, CFA)?)$";
string input = "John, Jan, Joe\nJohn, Jan, Joe, CPA, CFA\njake, jan, joe, john, jessie, jack, jones";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, @"$1 and $2", RegexOptions.Multiline));
```

Output

```
John, Jan and Joe
John, Jan and Joe, CPA, CFA
jake, jan, joe, john, jessie, jack and jones
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach however I have edited my question because maybe it was not clear enough. Basically I do not know how many names are in the string. So really to have proper english I just need to check to see if that last entry has a designation or not to account for the extra commas to add the and. So running your code if I add like five names to it then the and gets added to the third element not the very last one which is ultimately what I am concerned about.

Comment: @qiuzman Like this? `([^\s,]+,)(\s*(?:[^\s,]+(?:, CPA, CFA)?$))` https://regex101.com/r/BYUUs0/1

Comment: Can you add this to your answer above with the regex.replace function to make this complete and I will reselect as the chosen answer.

Comment: @qiuzman I have updated the answer and adjusted the pattern a little bit.

Comment: @Thefourthbird `John, Jan, Joe` The result should be  `John, Jan and Joe`

Comment: @qiuzman I have updated it.

Comment: What is interesting that I did not even realize is this regex does not work if the list includes last names "John Jacob, Jan Jasper, Joe Jordan, CPA, CFA"

Comment: @qiuzman Then you can omit the `\s` like `([^,]+),\s*([^,]+(?:, CPA, CFA)?)$` See https://regex101.com/r/HQ5fiq/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code without using `Regex`

```
//string input = "John, Jan, Joe, CPA, CFA";
string input = "John, Jan, Joe";
var result = input.Select((b, i) => b.Equals(',') ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToList();

if(input.EndsWith(", CFA"))
     input=input.Replace(input.Substring(0,result[result.Count()-3] +2), input.Substring(0, result[result.Count()-3]+2) + "and ");
else
     input = input.Replace(input.Substring(0, result[result.Count()-1] +1), input.Substring(0, result[result.Count()-1]) + " and ");

Console.WriteLine(input);
```

if `string input = "John, Jan, Joe, CPA, CFA"`:

> result: "John, Jan, and Joe, CPA, CFA" (Apparently, you have added an extra comma)

if  `string input = "John, Jan, Joe"`;

> result: John, Jan and Joe

Comment: If the list has more than just these people the count might not be 4. So your code looks like it would only work in the scenario if you knew the count of people which I dont. Thats why i use the EndsWith() to check if the last includes the designation CPA, CFA

Comment: @qiuzman You did not fully explain the question. You just said that I have two scenarios. I answered based on that. But the algorithm is correct. i edit the answer ...

Comment: Going to test this out now but I have added that caveat in the question as an edit so I apologize for not explicitly stating that.

Comment: Using your code and adding more names it does not behave as mentioned. Here is your code run in this sample:. https://dotnetfiddle.net/JMO4ug . In the code example provided if I added additional names it is still adding a and to after the third element. It needs to be dynamic since I do not know the count.

Comment: Your solution is actually also really flexible..